# How to return the results of a query using find() for a deep search level with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following structure of a collection:

```
teams: [{
  name: String,
  address: String,
  players: [{
    name: String,
    age: Integer
  }]
}]
```

I am trying to search by 'name' of the player. I am trying this:

```
db.teams.find({ players: { $elemMatch: { name: /john/ } } }, { 'players.$':1 })
```

This returns some results, but not all. And this:

```
db.teams.find({ players: { $elemMatch: { name: /john/ } } })
```

This last returns all the records of the collection.

I need to find by a player with its name as parameter.

What is right query?

Comment: The first query returns all the documents that have a player with name `/john/` and `project` only that player in the players array of each document. The second query selects all the documents that have a player with name `/john/` without any projection and not all the documents in the collection. Both these queries work fine. What is your intended output?

Comment: My intention is getting only the players with that condition. Only the players with /john/ name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common misconception about MongoDB. Queries in MongoDB do not match subdocuments; they do not return subdocuments. Queries match and return documents in the collection, with returned fields adjustable via projection. With your document structure, you cannot write a query that matches and returns one of the subdocuments in the array. You can (and have, in your examples), written a query to match documents containing an array element that matches a condition, and then project just the *first* matching element in the array. It's important to understand the difference. If you want to match and return player documents, your collection should contain player documents:

```
{
    "name" : "John Smalls",
    "age" : 29,
    "team_name" : "The Flying Sharks",
    "team_address" : "123 Fake Street"
}
```

The player documents reference their team. To find a player by name,

```
db.players.find({ "name" : /^John"/ })
```

To find all the players on a team,

```
db.players.find({ "team_name" : "The Flying Sharks" })
```

Your life will be much easier if you search for players by querying for player documents instead of trying to match team documents.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I think the best way is make a second collection like you said.